# Eclipse C++ error

Tags: c++, time

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: c1004527
 *
 * Created on February 15, 2012, 10:25 PM
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include "CardClass.h"
#include "PlayerClass.h"

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    srand(time(0));
    CardClass deck;
    PlayerClass player[4];
    deck.ShuffleCards();
    deck.Print();
    for(int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        player[i%4].AddACard(deck.DealCards());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        player[i].SortCard();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
       cout << endl << endl
            << "Player "<< i+1 << endl
             << player[i];
    }

    return (0);
}
```

The error is:

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               
**** g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o OLA3\OLA3\main.o ..\OLA3\OLA3\main.cpp
..\OLA3\OLA3\main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
..\OLA3\OLA3\main.cpp:17:17: error: 'time' was not declared in this scope
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 114  ms.
```

Everything else compiles completely fine but that. I use minGW and it compiles hello world with no problem.

Comment: Post your actual code. The only thing anybody can say at this point is precisely what the compiler error says: that you refer to a variable or function named `time` without having first declared it. I’m guessing you’re saying `srand(time(0))` without having said `#include <ctime>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've included `<ctime>`, `time` is going to be defined in the `std` namespace.
Therefore, you need to use a fully-qualified reference: `std::time`.

That's what this error is telling you:

> error: 'time' was not declared in this scope